# CSS to center menu with an image fixed to the left of the screen and one to the right of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling with the following css styling issue for quite some time now: 
I have 3 columns - An Image, my Menu and then another image

### Below is kinda how its meant to look:

### | image |            Menu Item 1 /  Menu Item 2  /   Menu Item 3       | image |

I need to have the left image to fixed on the left of my screen
The Right image must be fixed on the right of the screen
The menu items must be centered inside the middle column.

That way when I resize the screen the left and right menu stays where they are and the middle column resizes accordingly.

Can any one show me how the style this up?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

CSS

```
.imgleft {
   position:absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
.imgright {
   position:absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
.menuhead {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center
    min-width: 320px;     /* so menuhead not shrink more than links/images fit without overlap  */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='menuhead'>
    <img class='imgleft' src="" />

    Link1 | Link2

    <img class='imgright' src="" />
</div>
```

There are many options for doing this. Other ways are to have multiple background images aligned left and right or use div's instead of img's or add the images with :after/:before psuedo classes or .... (where some is not supported by older browsers)

To know which is better, the whole layout concept needs to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
    .wrap { overflow: hidden; }

    .leftImg {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }

    .nav {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 210px;
        margin-right: 210px;
    }

    .rightImg {
        width: 200px;
        float: right;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="rightImg"></div>
    <div class="leftImg"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>        
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hv6zH/)